# How to make a <div> full width to the browser edge?

Tags: html, css

I have created a quick example of a problem I am having.
As noted by the black border the div isn't going directly to the horizontal edge of the browser ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVAFQ.png)). Here is the relevant code.

```
border: 1px solid black;
display: block;
width: 100%;
height: 50px;
```

How can I change this?

Comment: Remove margins from body and remember to use search, you would've found the answer faster than typing up this question.

Comment: Check any base stylesheets.  You might need to apply a CSS Reset: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: All of the answers are covered. You might need to remove padding/margins from <body> and/or <html> or just nuke it and apply a reset.  @Nit -- way to Nit Pick!  :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll just need to reset the default margin values from the browser default stylesheet.

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Html-pages have margin by default. Remove it:

```
html{margin:0}
```

Answer (score 1):

`html,body{margin:0}` or try more complex reset styles like the one below. It will save you a lot of time in the future when checking inconsistencies between browsers:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

Comment: Completely unnecessary for what was asked.